# How to use setState outside the class with async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to use setState after I did a fetch on an api so I can load it into react.
The problem is that it is a async function so I can't use it inside the class itself.
How can I still change the state from outside the class itself?

I have a function `async function getUsers() {}` and in the class that's just under it `starte = {data: ''}`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear what your code looks like. *it is a async function so I can't use it inside the class itself* - how does the fact that it's async prevent it from being used? *How can I still change the state from outside the class itself?* - you usually shouldn't, all `state` logic belongs to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method from within the class and you will know when it is done so that you may call setState.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that deals with updating the state and pass that method to the getUsers function and trigger the callback from there.